# Intellij IDEA Web Project deployment

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Created a new Java Web Project from a scratch in Intellij IDEA, changed nothing here, and found out that my project starts by default at *localhost:8080/* in contrast to Eclipse, NetBeans, for example, where the project starts at *localhost:8080/WEB_PROJECT_NAME*.

The thing is that the default file index.jsp is always correctly displayed at *localhost:8080/index.jsp*
But I always got a 404 error, trying to access *localhost:8080/WEB_PROJECT_NAME/index.jsp*

Therefore, I have no opportunity to run any servlets or smth else.
Anything I try to access via localhost:8080/WEB_PROJECT_NAME/... gives me an error.

Here are my Run/Debug configurations:
[image: Run/Debug configurations]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Deployment** tab shown on your screenshot, you can specify the context for your web application there, lile `/WEB_PROJECT_NAME` instead of the default `/` (ROOT).

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem, that worked for me

Comment: @VyacheslavLogvinov Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.