# IntelliJ not serving war file properly with tomcat local deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am new to world of Java and IntelliJ IDE, I have an existing app in which I configured Tomcat module with all correct settings, when I run the project all the Artifacts are getting created and tomcat is getting started as well with correct logs and I can also see tomcat process in running on port 8080, but when I visit localhost:8080 it gives me page not found error, so can anybody help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have a index page?

Comment: _"when i visit localhost:8000"_ you mean 8080?

Comment: What's the application context? `http://localhost:8080` only works if the application is deployed on the root context (`/`).

Comment: If I copy the war file to apache webapps folder and start apache manually eveything works fine but when I start from IntelliJ it does not work , sorry I am very new to this whole thing so I am not aware what context is

Comment: @AjayBeniwal does https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056139/104891 help?